# Tomcat loaded the lower version spring libraries when debug in Intelli j idea

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I have a maven spring web(3.2.*) project build with target war, I want to debug it in intellij idea with tomcat(web:war exploded artifact), but the web application always failed to load,

> [ERROR]..|Context initialization failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:404)

Because in some pom dependencies, they referenced lower version spring(3.0.7), I can exclude them in the ware with maven-war-plugin(2.3):packagingExcludes, but how I can exclude them in web:war exploded.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>
            WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar,
            // others springframework jars
        </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven has a not easy to understand way how it resolves dependency conflicts. 
It's called the [nearest-wins strategy](http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/), which could lead to the usage of an older version.

Try to use [Maven Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in combination with the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to fixate version and to fail a build if you didn't define a dependency version explicit.

The easy way would be to [analyse the dependency graph with](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

check which dependency depends on the old spring library and exclude that like @alexandar-petrov already posted in his answer.

Excluding the dependency from the artifact you are building won't have any effects on the classpath that Intellij or any other IDE will use.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the plugin where you should exclude dependencies with respect of the IDE it is the dependency graph. Use mvn dependency:tree to see which module, dependency has included the old spring version. When you figure it out exclude it from the build.

Here is an example of how to use dependency exclusion coming straight from maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I used spring bom to manage the dependencies, I did not see the conflicts with maven helper, but the old version spring jars download and copied to the WEB-INF/lib folder